# Insertion Sort - Invalid Method Declaration

Tags: java, methods, insertion-sort

I was making a Insertion Sort Program that accepts (Int, Double, String) .. But i can't call a method , it say's invalid method declaration , i can't figure out what the real problem is.....................................

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyInsertionSort 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter anything you want: ");
    String insertionSort = in.nextLine(); 

    int num=Integer.parseInt(insertionSort);
    String array[] = new String [num];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Input the Number at array index "+i+": ");
      array[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
  }

  insertionSort(input);

  private static void printNumbers(int[] input) 
  { 
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
    { 
      System.out.print(input[i] + ", "); 
    } 
    System.out.println("\n"); 
  } 

  public static void insertionSort(int array[]) 
  { 
    int n = array.length; 
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) 
    { 
      int key = array[j]; 
      int i = j-1; 
      while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) 
      { 
        array [i+1] = array [i]; i--; 
      } 
      array[i+1] = key; 
      printNumbers(array); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a call to 'insertionSort()' just above the declaration of 'printNumbers()'. The format you provided is not really clear but this call seems outside any method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `insertionSort(input);` in your main method. Just move your method call to 1 line up.

Answer (score -3):

Your declared the method as

```
public static void insertionSort(int array[])
```

instead of

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array)
```